# How to for-each over items depending on the child values of the children?

Tags: xml, xslt

How do you make a `for-each` over elements with a condition that depends on values of the children's children?

Example XML of an item:

```
<z:item>
  <z:publications>
      <z:publication>
         <z:mediaKey>a</z:mediaKey>
         <z:publicationStatus>published</z:publicationStatus>
      </z:publication>
      <z:publication>
         <z:mediaKey>b</z:mediaKey>
         <z:publicationStatus>ready</z:publicationStatus>
      </z:publication>
      <z:publication>
         <z:mediaKey>c</z:mediaKey>
         <z:publicationStatus>ready</z:publicationStatus>
      </z:publication>
   </z:publications>
</z:item>
```

Now I want to make a `for-each` over all items that have `mediaKey!=a` and `publicationStatus=published`.

I tried this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//z:item[z:publication/@status = 'published' and z:publication/@mediaKey != 'zgonline']">
```

But this is wrong, because it also includes the item above which has `a/published` and others only in ready state.

When I do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//z:item/z:publication[@status = 'published' and @mediaKey != 'zgonline']">
```

then it selects the correct `publication` nodes, but the resulting node set will contain twice the above `item` because it fulfills twice the selecting criteria....

I actually want to do something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//z:item[z:publication[@status = 'published' and @mediaKey != 'zgonline']]">
```

How shall I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that this solution works just fine, you can have nested conditions:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//z:item[z:publication[@status = 'published' and @mediaKey != 'zgonline']]">
```

However, the proposed solution of @zx485 also works:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//z:item[z:publications/z:publication/z:publicationStatus = 'published' and z:publications/z:publication/z:mediaKey != 'a']">
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that

> [you] want to make a for-each over all `z:item`s that have a `mediaKey!='a'` and a `publicationStatus='published'`.

If this (your) question is correct, the correct answer will be

```
<xsl:for-each select="//z:item[z:publications/z:publication/z:publicationStatus = 'published' and z:publications/z:publication/z:mediaKey != 'a']">  
  <xsl:text>MATCHED</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

which would loop over all `z:item`s which have these two children with the given values.